# Is there a way to exclude certain keywords from a regexp_match statement in Tableau?

Tags: regex, database, if-statement, tableau-api

I am trying edit the calculation field and pull in filenames that contain the string 'NDA.' However, filenames that contain 'STANDARD' also get pulled in error. Is there a way to do this in Tableau? I have tried the follow but it becomes too restrictive and the majority of files I'd expect to pull don't get pulled no more.

```
 IF  REGEXP_MATCH(UPPER([Name]),'_NDA|NDA_|_NDA_|NDA<>STANDARD')THEN "Nondisclosure Agreement"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating it as a separate IF statement:

```
IF REGEXP_MATCH(UPPER([Name]),'STANDARD') THEN "Whatever you want here"
ELSE IF  REGEXP_MATCH(UPPER([Name]),'_NDA|NDA_|_NDA_')THEN "Nondisclosure Agreement"
```

On an unrelated note, you should think about using `Contains` instead of `Regexp_match`, since its usally better from a performance point of view.